# Is there a mechanism for replacing major party candidates who quit US presidential election?

Tags: united-states

Wondering if there are mechanism for replacing major party candidates who are already nominated but quit. For example, Donald Trump might quit due to a major scandal, or Hillary Clinton due to the federal investigation on her blowing up. Is there a mechanism for the parties to put another candidate on the ballot? If yes, what is the mechanism?

Comment: There [is](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11973/4666), but note that currently [ballots have already been set](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12051/4666) in some if not all states.  So the candidate would remain on the ballot in any state where it is past the revision deadline.  Also, some people may have already voted.

Comment: At least 400,000 ballots already cast, according to http://www.huffingtonpost.com/michael-p-mcdonald/early-voting-a-month-to-g_b_12424562.html