# Consequences of a late Non-Nomination of a US presidential candidate for ballots

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, ballot, nomination

Some aspects are covered already for the nominations themselves (e.g. [What is the procedure for choosing a new Republican candidate for the US presidency if the nominee withdraws or is removed?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11941/25067) and [A presidential candidate drops out after nomination](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11973/25067)). These focus one the respective national convention's nomination.

**This question is about having a name on the ballot.**

At least this year (2020), the **deadlines for ballot access have passed in July** (See example of Kanye West's announcement considered too late: https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-election/kanye-west-2020-running-for-president-legal-possible-forbes-interview-deadline-trump-a9608596.html), but **the conventions are only taking place now (in mid August).**

Question:
**What would happen to the ballots if either of the parties would not nominate the presumptive candidates**, or they would not accept, or the nomination would swap the presumptive president and vice-president role?

Comment: *deadlines for ballot access have passed in July*  You probably should clear that up as Democratic and Republican conventions have historically been in August.  I think those earlier deadlines refer to independent candidates.

Comment: @JustMe Thanks for this hint. I like the question and your comment to leave a they are, because this difference for independent candidates seems to be the root cause of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recognized parties (the criteria will vary from state to state, but generally require the party to have met a registration threshold or general election threshold in the previous election), there will be a reserved slot with its own deadline. For example, in Michigan,

> A state-recognized political party must certify to the secretary of
> state the names and addresses of its candidates for president, vice
> president and presidential electors. This certification must be filed
> "within one business day after the conclusion of the party's state
> convention or national convention (whichever is later)."

https://ballotpedia.org/Ballot_access_requirements_for_presidential_candidates_in_Michigan#Party_nomination_processes